# Transclusion when using directive as attribute

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am having trouble with the way angular manages directives as attributes.

I have an element directive that are using transclusions:

```
<xx-button>Button!</xx-button>
```

And I have a directive that changes the content of an element by adding some other directives to it:

```
<xx-button xx-modifying-directive>Button!</xx-button>
```

This will be modified to:

```
<xx-button some-other-directives>
  <button>Button!</button>
</xx-button>
```

When I compile the content of the element in the linking function of the `xx-modifying-directive` directive, I get the following error:

> Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found. Element:

You can see the problem more clearly in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jedi/m3objL56/3/).

Reading the doc, or ngRepeat's source code I don't see how to fix that problem.

Note: I need to compile my element in `xx-modifying-directive` because this directive adds other directives that needs to be compile (in my practical case I'm adding hammer handlers like `hm-pan`).

**Update:**

Looking more closely, the problem comes from the fact that the (ngTransclude directive)[https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2a156c2d7ec825ff184480de9aac4b0d7fbd5275/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js#L59] is not passed the transclude function.

Still don't know why because it actually has an ancestor for which transclude is activated (`xx-button`).

Comment: You're trying to manually compile the (parent) element on which the attribute directive is declared, which is incorrect and doesn't in fact achieve anything. The compile service should be used with a new template string, which you generate dynamically. Please read carefully through the service documentation, it's perhaps one of the most complex and hard to understand angular topics.

Comment: I believe 'element' represent <xx-button>, and as directives are added to this element it needs to be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$transclude` function has to be provided to `$compile`. It is passed to the `link` function.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, $transclude) {
  [...]
  if ($transclude) { // It can be undefined if not content is provided
    $compile(element, $transclude)(scope);
  }
  [...]
}
```

If you want to go deeper into the transclusion busines, follow this [link](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/06/09/transclusion.html).